# How to enable bot to be added to Teams group conversation

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I built a web app bot in Azure with https://www.qnamaker.ai/. My teammates can also access the bot if they have the link to the Teams channel of the bot. But I can't add the bot to a group/channel in Teams.

How do I enable the bot to be added to group Conversation？

Comment: Did you enable teams channel on azure portal?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes it can be used on Teams, just cannot in group chats

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, some [clarification of terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet):

- `teams` Also called channel conversations, visible to all members of the channel.
- `personal` Conversations between bots and a single user.
- `groupChat` Chat between a bot and two or more users. Also enables your bot in meeting chats.

To allow your bot to chat in a team or group chat in App Studio:

Under the "Bots" tab (you may need to click Edit, next to your bot), ensure the appropriate scope is selected:

[image]

Then, under "Test and distribute", use "Add to a chat" to add it to an existing group chat, or "Add to a team" to add it to a Team to use in Channels chats:

[image]

Comment: what is app studio?